# Using keys normally and as modifiers in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I remapped a few combinations of the menu key and other alphanumeric keys with AutoHotKey, but in doing so it disabled the normal use of the menu key. Is there a way that I can remap combinations of the key, but leave its normal use the same with AHK. I'll put the code I'm currently using with it below. Thanks

```
AppsKey & m::DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", 2000, "int", 1440)  ; The first number is the X-coordinate and the second is the Y (relative to the screen).
AppsKey & =:: Send {U+2248}
AppsKey & x:: Send {U+00D7}
```

Comment: See [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs that user3419297 mentioned](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo), you can get around this by putting `AppsKey::AppsKey` at the end of your script. However, this will cause the menu key to do its normal function only once you *release* the Menu key, provided that you have not hit any other keys during that time (as opposed to when you initially push it down). If this change in functionality did not occur, you would be triggering the menu key's standard function every time you attempted to hold it down in order to trigger any of your hotkeys.

### Final Script

```
AppsKey & m::DllCall("SetCursorPos", "int", 2000, "int", 1440)  ; The first number is the X-coordinate and the second is the Y (relative to the screen).
AppsKey & =:: Send {U+2248}
AppsKey & x:: Send {U+00D7}
AppsKey::AppsKey
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added in the following line and it works like a charm. It's a bit different than the solution you gave me, but it should function similarly.
`$AppsKey::Send {AppsKey}`

Comment: For some reason it made the menu key stop working, but only in some apps for some reason. I'm not sure what caused this. I ended up just using a different key instead of the menu key, and now it works fine.